# How to programmatically write IP packet bytes into PCAP file format?

Tags: java, c, networking

Assuming that I have a set of buffers that represents an IP packet, how can generate a PCAP file? I'm looking for an API to do this in C/C++ or Java.

Comment: I was able to do it myself in pure Java by following this documentation: http://www.kroosec.com/2012/10/a-look-at-pcap-file-format.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jnetpcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) includes the class [PcapDumper](http://jnetpcap.sourceforge.net/docs/jnetpcap-1.0-javadoc/org/jnetpcap/PcapDumper.html) which will write an array of bytes to a pcap file as [documented here](http://jnetpcap.com/node/69).

[note to original questioner: this answer was downvoted because i answered your question, and criticised others for closing a reasonable question, not because the answer is actually wrong in any way]

Comment: They don't write an array of bytes to a file on http://jnetpcap.com/node/69 It looks like they capture packets and write them to the file