# Write an array of bytes representing an IP packet to a pcap file

Tags: java, wireshark, packet

I capture an IPv4 packet in an app like [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java) To make sure I handle the read packet correctly [I was told](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60724813&postcount=105) to save it and the response I create to a pcap file and open it in WireShark.

I use [jnetpcap-1.3.0-1.win64](http://jnetpcap.com/?q=download)

As for writing to the file, I found an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19170377/1065835

Both examples from http://jnetpcap.com/node/69 throw the same NPE here:

```
PcapDumper dumper = pcap.dumpOpen(ofile); // output file
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

This is my code:

```
StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder();
String fname = "test-afs.pcap";
new File(fname).createNewFile();
Pcap pcap = Pcap.openOffline(fname, errbuf);

String ofile = "tmp-capture-file.cap";
new File(ofile).createNewFile();
PcapDumper dumper = pcap.dumpOpen(ofile); // output file

pcap.loop(10, dumper); // Special native dumper call to loop

File file = new File(ofile);
System.out.printf("%s file has %d bytes in it!\n", ofile, file.length());

dumper.close(); // Won't be able to delete without explicit close
pcap.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JavaDoc for `Pcap.dumpOpen()`](http://jnetpcap.com/docs/javadocs/jnetpcap-1.4/org/jnetpcap/Pcap.html#dumpOpen%28java.lang.String%29) states

> **Parameters**: `fname` - specifies the name of the file to open; currently the libpcap option to open stdout by using "-" as a string, is not supported by jNetPcap

You're creating the very file that Pcap is going to open in the next LoC. That's not going to work, I think...:

```
String ofile = "tmp-capture-file.cap";
new File(ofile).createNewFile();
PcapDumper dumper = pcap.dumpOpen(ofile); // output file - BUT IT EXISTS!
```

In either case, you might get lucky surrounding the line with a `try`-`catch` and see if `Pcap.getErr()` has anything meaningful in the `catch` clause, but I'm betting on an already-exists issue.

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by the file path issue? The separator char /? I added my code.

Comment: I created the files I'm going to use before using them. Please take a look at my code

Comment: Amended answer completely - have a look.