# converting ByteBuffer data to Pcap format

Tags: java, android, pcap, bytebuffer

I had a created a localhost VPN server on android and my packets are in ByteBuffer format.
In order to verify the packet's correctness I need to save the packets in a pcap file.
Is there viable package or way to achieve this? 
I have tried searching in jpcap,pcap4j and few more repos but no luck.

I had looked into [How to programmatically write IP packet bytes into PCAP file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170185/how-to-programmatically-write-ip-packet-bytes-into-pcap-file-format)

That answer captures packets and writes to a file where as here the packets are available in ByteBuffer format and I would like to write it to a pcap file. I thought of converting it into a byte array and write but still unsuccessful.

```
private void process(ByteBuffer packet,int type) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String s = new String(packet.array(),charset);
    byte[] b = s.getBytes();

    //convert into pcap and erite into file

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically write IP packet bytes into PCAP file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170185/how-to-programmatically-write-ip-packet-bytes-into-pcap-file-format)

Comment: please reconsider the question https://stackoverflow.com/users/6884590/pchaigno

Comment: Please read that duplicate more carefully and read the documentation ;) [The `dump` method](http://jnetpcap.sourceforge.net/docs/jnetpcap-1.0-javadoc/org/jnetpcap/PcapDumper.html) takes a `ByteBuffer`.